# What are the javascript parts in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table, tr

Can someone explain to me the parts of the for loops?

```
for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        grid += '<tr class="row-' + i + '">';
        // loop for each cell
        for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            grid += '<td class="cell" id="row-' + i + '_cell-' + j + '"></td>';
        }
        grid += '</tr>';
    }
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the grid parts. How can I write it in a different way?

Comment: different way? whats not working? for is used in this implementation because x needs a loop and y needs a loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the grid is simply making `height` number of rows and `width` number of rows. The grid will store this HTML code and then it must probably be replacing it somewhere using Html DOM manipulation.

> What are the javascript parts in this for loop?

The loop is part of javascript, the `height`, `width`, `grid` variables are part of javascript. Even the HTML code you are storing is part of javascript since it is being stored in `grid` which is just another  JS variable.

You can refer the below code to see what the code is really doing -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


  <p>This example demonstrates the <b>making a table using JS</b> method.</p>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  //var is used to store the HTML code, height and width store the number of rows and columns of table
    var grid = "<table>",
      height = 5,
      width = 5;
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      grid += '<tr class="row-' + i + '">';
      // loop for each cell
      for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        grid += '<td class="cell" id="row-' + i + '_cell-' + j + '"> (' + i + ' , ' + j + ' ) &emsp;&emsp;  </td>';
      }
      grid += '</tr>';
    }
    grid += "</table>";
    // Below we are just replacing the HTML in p with HTML that we filled in grid
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = grid;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The *grid* variable is practically the content of the table. On each *grid* line, a new HTML element is generated (except the last one).

For i iterations, a new row is added with a class name equivalent to the iteration index. Considering how rows are indexed vertically on a table, *height* is used as a metric for the y axis.

Similarly, j iterations add a new cell into the current 'i' row. Considering how a cell is combination of a row and column on a table, *width* is used as a metric for the x axis.

After the second  (j) loop is finished, the closing tag `</tr>`is added in order to close the current iterated row.

Answer (score 0):

The grid part is just a variable name the programmer chose. It is a simple nestes for loop that will produce html that will look like this (for a 1x1 input)

With the variables i and j representing the index of their loop.